# Update a Textblock in ViewModel from another Class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I have created an interface (ViewModel) for my application to control my elements. I want to set a text for a Textblock in a class.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class Model
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model;
    public ViewModel()
    {
     _model = new Model();
    }
    
    string username;
    public string Username { 
        get => username; 
        set
        {
            if(username != value)
            {
                username = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(_model.Username));
                
            }
        } 
    }

    

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(name)));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MyClass:**

```
Model Model = new Model();
        Model.Username = "name";
```

when i set the Username in `public ViewModel() { Username = "test"; }` It works.

**XMAL:**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local1:ViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public"  Text="{Binding Username}"/>
```

Comment: Where are you binding your `Model` instance to the XAML's `DataContext`?

Comment: 1. You never use the Model instance in ViewModel. Why? 2. You call RaisePropertyChanged method twice. Why?

Comment: @SirRufo Oh sorry I forgot to change it after testing

Comment: But that does not really change anything. You only use the Model instance for getting the name of its property Username, and that does not make sense in any way

Answer (score 2):

You must raise the `PropertyChanged` for the property that is the member of binding source. When you bind to a class `ViewModel`, you must raise the event for the property on this object and not on any unrelated objects like your class `Model`.

Since you don't want to bind directly to classes of the model, you must delegate the properties or write the values back to the model at the proper point in time e.g. after invocation of a save command.

If the model can change data independently and your view model needs to know about these changes, then the view model must observe the model. To enable observation, the model must expose corresponding events.

To delegate the property data received from the view to the model, implement property delegation:

```cs
// Update the model immediately after e.g., the data binding has changed the property
public string Username 
{ 
  get => this.Model.Username; 
  set
  {
    if (this.Model.Username != value)
    {
      this.Model.Username = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();                
    }
  } 
}
```

To observe data changes in a class of the model, introduce a corresponding event. This event can notify about particular changes e.g., a particular property like `UsernameChanged`, or it can be more general and notify about certain state changes like `UserDataChaged` or `DataChanged`:

**ValueChangedEventArgs.cs**

```cs
public class ValueChangedEventArgs<TValue> : EventArgs
{
  public ValueChangedEventArgs(TValue oldValue, TValue newValue)
  {
    this.OldValue = oldValue;
    this.NewValue = newValue;
  }

  public TValue NewValue { get; }
  public TValue OldValue { get; }
}
```

**Model.cs**

```cs
public class Model
{
  protected virtual void OnUsernameChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    => this.UsernameChanged?.Invoke(this, new ValueChangedEventArgs<string>(oldValue, newValue));

  public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs<string>> UsernameChanged;

  private string username;
  public string Username 
  { 
    get => this.username; 
    set
    {
      if (this.Username != value)
      {
        string oldValue = this.Username;
        this.username = value;
        OnUsernameChanged(oldValue, this.Username);                
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Model = new Model();
    this.Model.UsernameChanged += OnModelUsernameChanged;
  }

  private void OnModelUsernameChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs<string> e)
  {
    if (e.NewValue != this.Username)
    {
      RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Username));      
    }
  }  

  // Update the model immediately after e.g., the data binding has changed the property
  public string Username 
  { 
    get => this.Model.Username; 
    set
    {
      if (this.Model.Username != value)
      {
        this.Model.Username = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();                
      }
    } 
  }

  private Model Model { get; }
}
```

Consider to hide details of the model class to add more robustness in terms of modifications to the model's implementation. For example, don't expose the properties of a model class directly. Rather build its API around a set of methods that allow to modify it. You could introduce a `SaveUser(User) : void` method, where `User` is the class to encapsulate user related data (to reduce the parameter count). Now, instead of having the view model class to know which properties and methods it has to use in order to update a user, it simply invokes the `SaveUser()` method. The view model must not know about the internals of the model.

---

To fix the update issue related to two different instances of `Model`, you must initialize all depending classes (the `ViewModel` class and the `MyClass` class) with the *same* `Model` instance (shared instance).
Since we have to manually instantiate the `ViewModel` in order to pass the `Model` instance to the constructor, you must remove the `ViewModel` instantiation and `DataContext` assignment from the XAML of MainWIndow.xaml (and every other XAML where it is used as `DataContext` too):

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var sharedModelInstance = new Model();
 
        // Instantiate the ViewModel using the shared Model instance and assign it to the DataContext
        var viewModel = new ViewModel(sharedModelInstance);
        this.DataContext = viewModel;

        // Initialize MyClass using the shared Model
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(sharedModelInstance);        
        mc.UserData();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**
Replace the constructor of the `ViewModel` example from above with this one:

```cs
public ViewModel(Model model) 
{
  this.Model = model;
  this.Model.UsernameChanged += OnModelUsernameChanged;
}
```

**MyClass.cs**
Modify the constructor of MyClass to accept a Model instance which MyClass then uses (instead of creating its own instance):

```cs
private Model UserModel { get; }
public MyClass(Model model)
{
  this.Model = model;
}
```

Now, that the `ViewModel` is assigned to the `DataContext` in the constructor of `MainWindow`, you probably miss the design time `Intellisense` support. To improve the experience, you must define a design time instance of `ViewModel`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel}">
</Window>
```

Comment: Ahh, right. Of course. What a shame ;) Thank you for reviewing the solution!

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, but when I put a value on the model nothing changes and nothing is displayed in the TextBlock

Comment: Does the TextBlock bind to the `Username` property of the class `ViewModel` ?

Comment: Yes `Text="{Binding Username}`

Comment: Then how do you modify the `Model.Username` property? You must make sure that you use the exact same instance that is assigned to the `ViewModel.Model` property.

Comment: `public Model UserModel = new Model(); // Model.cs 
UserModel .Username = "username";`

Comment: But you are then using two different instances. One to update the username and one for data binding in your ViewModel class. You must use the same instance.

Comment: Where do you use UserModel? Can you post the related code please?

Comment: I use it in a class that I execute at the start of the application. And I want to set a value for username in the model.

Comment: Can you please add the related code to your question so that I can modify it for you? I guess App.xaml.cs?

Comment: Which code do you mean? Do you mean the one I use to run the class?

Comment: Yes. You said you modify the Model on application start. That's why I assumed the relevant code is in App.xaml.cs. If you want me to show you how to use a shared instance then you must show me how your application is structured. I need to see at least how you start the application and when and where you need to modify the model.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you an example on how to distribute a shared instance. Now modifications to the state of this instance is visible to all other classes that depend on the same type. Remember: to share the data or state of an object between multiple classes, those classes must use the same instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I have one last Question. How can I bind the Username now to the TextBlock, because it is not available in the Binding?

Comment: The ViewModel is available. You have assigned it to the DataContext from the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: Maybe it's not visible for Intellisense. To improve the experience, define a design time instance. Wait i will give you an example.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You find the example at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

your class should look like this: 
(you want to use different name for ModelField probably)

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string username;
    public string Username { 
        get => username; 
        set
        {
            if(username != value)
            {
                username = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
                
            }
        }
```

...
}

```
internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model;
    public ViewModel()
    {
     _model = new Model();
    }
    

    public Model ModelField { 
        get => _model; 
        set
        {
            if(_model != value)
            {
                _model = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ModelField));
                
            }
        } 
    }
...
}
```

and the xaml should bind to ModelField.UserName

Comment: The view model should not expose it's references to the model in order to ensure that it won't be illegally used by the view. In your code the model is bleeding through to the view.  You probably want to avoid implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on a model class. This way you avoid over-exposing model internals and make the unwanted data binding less convenient. Never bind the view to the model.